# Saving data in Flutter PageView

Tags: flutter

**Situation (Flutter App):**
I have PageView with four pages. On each page are controls like TextField, DropDownMenu,.. On the last page is button "Finish". When the button is pressd, app use settings from pages and do something.

**Question:**
At what event should I save data into shared preferences to use them later? Exist for pages an event like onClose?

Thank you very much for every advice
(apologize for my English)

Comment: It seems like it is really up to you when you want to save the data into `SharedPreferences`. If you have a button `Finish` then you could save your data when `onTap` is called.

Answer (score 0):

Use this [shared preferences library](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/shared_preferences) to save shared preferences.

1. Assign controllers to the input fields and as well as dropdowns:

   `TextEditingController nameController = new TextEditingController();`
2. Assign controller to fields:

   ```
    TextField(
         controller: nameController,
         decoration: new InputDecoration(
          hintText: "Name"
         )
    );
   ```
3. Create an `onPressed` or `onTap` method to the Finish button and fetch and save shared preferences:

   ```
     _saveData() async {
        SharedPreferences savePref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        String name = nameController.text;
        name.isEmpty ? _validateName = true : _validateName = false;
        savePref.setString("name", name);
     }
   ```

You can get saved shared preferences as:

```
String name = savePref.getString("name");
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Maybe I'll ask stupidly, but flutter keeps in memory all the created pages from PageView? Can't it happen that when I reach the last page, the first one will be destroyed? Can't I lose settings on some pages, such as when I suspend an application?

Comment: Do you want to destroy data of the first page or want to prevent it from destroying?

Comment: Nothing from this. When I switch the page, I see that the dispose method is called for previous page. Can I still access to variables of this object (page)? Isn't it already destroyed?

Comment: It would be okay if I:
1.) in the initState (page widget) method, read values from SharedPreferences and set them to TextEditingController
2.) in the dispose method, read from TextEditingController and save with SharedPreferences?

Comment: Both are okay, just make sure to read only required values in `initState` method

Comment: OK. Thank you for your help